# How to implement a check box in the index page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a index page that lists all the homes.I have a Boolean field called active for the homes.We want have a check box on the index page so that a user can check the homes he want to activate.How can this be done??

```
    <div style="margin-top:25px; margin-bottom:150px;">
       <div class="container">
       <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-2">
            <ul class="sidebar-list">
                <li class="sidebar-item"><%= link_to "Homes", homes_path, class:"sidebar-link active"%></li>


            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading" style="background-color:#6dae4e;">
                    Homes(<%= @homes.length %>)
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                        <% @homes.each do |home| %>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <%= image_tag home.home_photos[0].image.url if home.home_photos.length > 0 %>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-2">
                                <h4><%= link_to home.name, home %></h4>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-3 right">
                                <%= link_to "Edit", edit_home_path(home), class: "btn btn-green"%>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <hr/>
                    <% end %>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Follow this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6657801/rails3-update-boolean-checkbox-from-index-view

Comment: What's wrong in using `check_box_tag` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a check_box_tag

http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper/check_box_tag

```
<%= check_box_tag 'active' %>
```